# Why i get the following error while managing the api from my broker

Tags: python, api

Error is following. Note:- I am new to coding & have learned everything i know from Youtube. So please help me out with this technical errors.

I am creating command line in Python/Scripts, is it the reason, Please guide.

```
ERROR: Error [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified while executing command git version
ERROR: Cannot find command 'git' - do you have 'git' installed and in your PATH?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download and Install git in your windows from here:

https://git-scm.com/download/win

Then add its installation bin path to your windows's environment path. Then you will find the git command at the command prompt globally.

This may solve you problem.